# How can I execute a .bat file when Blender starts?

Tags: python, scripting

I have to start a postgresql server when blender starts. To start the server I use a .bat file I start manually.

I want to automatically start the server (execute the .bat) when Blender starts. I tried this script but it not working. ideas?

```
import subprocess
filepath="C:\Users\PORTABLE\Desktop\pgsql_binaire\pgsql\test.bat"
p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Comment: Dont you need double slashes or forward slash?  c:\\folder\\file or c:/folder/file

Comment: When I use \\ or / and I execute the script, Blender not responding!

Comment: do you start it and let it run in the background? check if postgresql has started. check this question for starting a process and letting it run in the background. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/starting-a-background-process-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be simpler to start both blender and postgresql using the same .bat file. Then point any blender shourtcuts/links you have at that file?

Comment: How can I start postgresql since all .blend files?

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question. Here is a code that works for me:

```
import bpy
import os
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\PORTABLE\\Desktop\\batfile")
os.sytsem("hello.bat)
```